# PHPstan Cannot access property $children on App\Account|null

Tags: php, laravel, phpstan

when I run PHPstan at level 8, I get for example with this code:

```
 /**
     * @return Collection<int, Account>
    */
    public function getCustomersAttribute(): Collection
    {
        return $this->account->children;
    }
```

I get the following message:

Cannot access property $children on App\Account|null

I also get this message with many other classes, only with a different attribute.

Since I cannot determine any access to this accessor e.g.

```
$model->customers
```

I also don't know whether an empty collection is always returned or zero (not my project, but taken over from an ex-colleague). So no error would be displayed:

```
/**
     * @return Collection<int, Account>|null
    */
    public function getCustomersAttribute(): Collection|null
    {
        return $this->account?->children;
    }
```

I suspect that PHPstan does not recognise that the account attribute is only referenced at runtime. Is there a PHPstan annotation for the Account class to tell PHPstan that the Account model can be null? Can anyone help me with this. I have about 100 of these messages and don't want to check for null everywhere since the code works.

I have tried in some places to check if the attribute is zero and if it is, I have returned zero, which has often led to errors. PHPstan should be able to recognise that the account model can also be null.

Comment: Extract a [mcve] first. Then, decide whether a bug report or a question here is in place.

Comment: What does `Account` have defined (PHPDoc block)? If you have no doc block at all inside `Account`, it will never work

Comment: You can use the [ide helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) to generate the implicit model properties.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Hello, what exactly would I need to define in the account model with the PHPDoc block? The class or do I need to create a variable there like public `Account $account`? Sorry for the stupid question but I've only been working with PHP and Laravel for a few weeks.

Comment: @apokryfos Hello, I had a look at this: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdocs-for-models but it didn't help me. The errors are still displayed

Comment: @michael.brilz you have to use the IDE Helper that apokryfos shared. Then run `php artisan ide:model` but write `yes`, you want to stuff to be inside each model, not on a single file called `_ide_models.php` (or similar), you want the properties to be inside each model file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Laravel uses Eloquent (Eloquent does not define the model's properties anywhere in the class for PHP to recognize), then PHPStan is not able to know what `Account` has as properties (remember Eloquent have them defined dynamically).

So, you have to define what the model has using PHPDoc blocks. Let me give you a super quick example of what you should expect to have inside `Account`:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @property int $id
 */
class Account extends Model
{
    // ...
}
```

Adding `@property int $id` will tell the IDE and PHPStan that `Account` has a property, it is an `integer` and is called `id`, so if you try `$account->` it should autocomplete `id` and show it is an `integer`.

Instead of you manually doing this, [`barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) already created a package for these types of things. Install it using `composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` and then you have to have all your migrations run `php artisan ide-helper:models -W` (you need to have the schema available, not data inside the table, it does not care about data).

Using `-W` will automatically insert the generated PHPDoc blocks inside each model class, if you do not do use `-W`, it will ask you if you want to generate a file called `_ide_helper_models.php` and put the PHPDoc blocks there, you don't want to do that, I think PHPStan will not recognize that.

What you can also try is using `php artisan ide-helper:models -M`, `-M` will still create the `_ide_helper_models.php` but add a `@mixin` tag inside each model class, so it relates the model class with the definition inside the `_ide_helper_models.php` file.

In the end, [this example](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdocs-for-models) is what you should have somewhere (and related to each model):

```php
/**
 * App\Models\Post
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $author_id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $text
 * @property \Illuminate\Support\Carbon $created_at
 * @property \Illuminate\Support\Carbon $updated_at
 * @property-read \User $author
 * @property-read \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Comment[] $comments
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\Models\Post newModelQuery()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\Models\Post newQuery()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\Models\Post query()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\Models\Post whereTitle($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\Models\Post forAuthors(\User ...$authors)
 * …
 */
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick help. I have now tried this with -W instead of -M and at least a few messages from PHPStan have disappeared. I'll have to see how I can fix the rest. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @michael.brilz If you are not able to fix those new issues, create a new question stating all of them and we will try to help you

Comment: Hello, the problem is still the same only with a different model `Cannot access property $catalog on App\Models\Catalog\Module|null.` Although I ran the ide-helper and the annotations were done, I get the same error only with different properties or methods. ```/***@property-read \App\Models\Catalog\Catalog|null $catalog*/ class Module extends BaseModel{} ```

Comment: Okay, create a new question or update the existing one with this info, add `---` after the last part of your question (if using the same one) and add all the new info. I would create a new question as the original error was fixed